# Redis sort unique key values

Tags: redis

I'm trying to sort all of my redis key's values to find all of the unique values.  I'm struggling to find the commands that will allow querying the keys to find all unique values.

`Step 1:  KEYS *`

Note:  This will show all 65,000 keys.

`Step 2:  GET k4n9gk5bu4k8usc3828g8fm699`

Result:  This `GET key` command will return a value of 'user'

Desired result:  Let us say that of the 65,000 entries, most of them are users.  How do I find what some of the other possible values have been set to, such as "administrator" or other values using redis commands and without having to code a script that loops through all 65,000 key's values?  In the UNIX world it would be something like this if the file contained unique values of 'user' and then some of the unique ones:

`cat file.txt | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Redis Set structure when save these values. for example:

you have the key `k4n9gk5bu4k8usc3828g8fm699` and value `user`, after you run the redis command `set k4n9gk5bu4k8usc3828g8fm699 user`, run `sadd unique_values_set user`.

If you want to get all the unique values. just run `smembers unique_values_set`.

Comment: I can't get this to work.  There are already 65,000 keys that have been created.  I'm trying to come in afterwards and query the unique values.  I think those commands are for when the values are set?  Or maybe I'm not understanding you.  Is there a way to query for the unique values of the keys after they have been created with set XXX user?

Comment: If they already created, the only way is get all keys and loop.